# Maximum likelihood estimate lies outside the paramater space

Tags: statistics

Say if I have a model where I impose the restriction that $\hat{\theta} \in (0,1)$, and I calculate the MLE to $\not\in (0,1)$, does this mean my model is incorrect, for this parameter restriction?

Comment: It simply means that your calculation of the MLE has failed to take into account the restriction you imposed.  What is the estimate that leads to the maximum likelihood *within* the restrictions?  That should be your REML estimate.

Comment: Too broad. For a useful answer, I think you'll need to share the specific example that prompted your question.